# Get Hibernate single iteration values only in an entity

Tags: spring, hibernate

I need to get values from user table, in that user have an manager id, 
Manager is an user so again manager id is  mapped with user entity.

This will cause continuous iteration until the manager ID get null.
\
The entity get more on inside on it > User entity > manager id> --> user entity ....

Is there any possible to get single entity with single manager using hibernate query?

```
 USER_NAME (PK)
CREATE_DATE
UPDATED_DATE
ROLE_ID
USER_ID
MANAGER_ID
REGION_ID
USER_GROUP
Created_By


User class

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long userId;


@ManyToOne( targetEntity = User.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "MANAGER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
private User managerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can relate to entity only managerId(I mean Long type), or you can mark Many to one relation with fetch = FetchType.LAZY and call this field only if needed.

Comment: Yes I have done same thing in my application, but the issue is stable application working on final stage, they called it in more 1200 references, once change it need to check the entire flow of the application it not possible at pre prod stage.

Comment: I am in the stage of performance issue fixation, so the performance we are doing should not affect the actual flow.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply